# Using Shared Memory in a Dynamic-Link Library in Visual C

Tags: c, shared-libraries, syntax-error

I'm trying to use the dll in the link below that allows for shared memory between different process. Though for some reason it's not compiling. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
First I have the dll compiled as written as a .lib. Then I create a new source file with the exact code as in the parent process. Just compiling I get the error

```
"Warning: empty declaration, syntax error found string constant expecting ;,unrecognized declaration"
```

for the line:

```
extern "C" VOID __cdecl SetSharedMem(LPWSTR lpszBuf)
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
extern "C" VOID __cdecl SetSharedMem(LPWSTR lpszBuf);
                                                   ^^^
```

It seems You have Missed the semicolon while copy pasting it.